# I want to update the Ace code editor with uploaded file contents specially for python file

Tags: file, tabs, ace-editor, code-editor

I have created a web-based code editor using the ACE editor on a streamlit, it creates the code editor box, and on top of it I have created the open file option where I am exploring the Python file, but when I select the file, the file content is not shown in the code editor or not updating the file content in the code editor. if you know how it will solve, share your solution. Thanks in advance!

I Tried with the text box, but I want to update the code editor with uploaded file content.